# On the "pedagogical practices, observations, and advances" in an academic job application?

Tags: teaching, tenure-track, teaching-statement

As a part the required statement of teaching associated with an academic job application, I need to explain my "pedagogical practices, observations, and advances". I searched a bit and figured out that pedagogical practices are fivefold, say, constructive, collaborative, reflective, integrative, and inquiry-based. However, I have the following ambiguities.

1- May I explain my experience in all of those five approaches and claim that my teaching style will be a mixture of all of them, or I better pick a subset of them to focus on?

2- What are those "observations and advances" part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is asking about your teaching philosophy. It is a combination of all that you believe teaching and learning should be about. If you've had a teaching experience, what downsides have you observed and how best did you solve or will try to solve them, should you have another chance. It gives a complete overview of what you see teaching and learning to be.

Answer (score 1):

Based solely on the common meaning of words, I would think that "practices" is what you do/have done, "observations" is what you have seen/noticed, and "advances" is what you think you do better now compared to your early practice.

As to the five elements of practice you list, I don't see a source, so it is difficult to say if this breakdown is a commonly accepted pedagogical theory or not.  In any case, since it appears you only just searched for it in response to writing the application, it would be somewhat insincere (premature?) to say that your teaching practice will reflect all five elements.  It would be better just to describe your actual teaching practice as it exists, and explain the approach you take to teaching.  If there are elements of overlap with this theory you found (from some mysterious source) then so be it, but don't overdo it trying to conform your description to the theory.

For the "observations and advances" part it would be useful to explain what important things you have observed in your teaching (e.g., what worked well, what went badly, etc.) and how you have improved your teaching as a result.  If you have had any experiences where you tried methods that didn't work, or you changed some aspect of your teaching and got better/worse results, etc., it is worth mentioning this as part of your overall explanation of your preferred practice.  Aside from wanting to know that you are a competent teacher, the admissions committee is going to want to see that you are a reflective person who can take in feedback on your teaching and adapt your methods to improve over time.